# Add Select and Write Privileges to User for Specific Table Names

Tags: oracle

I have created a new user using the below in sql developer (Oracle 11g).  I have only two tables titled FEED_DATA_A and FEED_DATA_B that I want this user to be able to select, update and insert into.  Can someone help me understand the SQL to create the proper privileges to accomplish that?  I'm currently logged in as the system user.

```
CREATE USER "USER_A" IDENTIFIED BY "test123";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to grant the privileges directly to the user

```
GRANT select, update, insert 
   ON table_owner.feed_data_a
   TO user_a;
GRANT select, update, insert 
   ON table_owner.feed_data_b
   TO user_a;
```

More commonly, though, you would create a role, grant the role to the user, and grant the privileges to the role.  That makes it easier in the future when there is a new user created that you want to have the same privileges as USER_A to just grant a couple of roles rather than figuring out all the privileges that potentially need to be granted.  It also makes it easier as new tables are created and new privileges are granted to ensure that users that should have the same privileges continue to have the same privileges.

```
CREATE ROLE feed_data_role;

GRANT select, update, insert 
   ON table_owner.feed_data_a
   TO feed_data_role;
GRANT select, update, insert 
   ON table_owner.feed_data_b
   TO feed_data_role;

GRANT feed_data_role
   TO user_a
```